# Animated container / row backgrounds

Tags: wordpress, animation, containers

Can anyone tell me how to get more information and learn how to create similar backgrounds to this site - https://greatminds.training/

The header background image moves and there is another one a little further down the page that also has animation behind the static text.

What componets are being used to create this effect?

Comment: I recommend looking into SVG animations.

Comment: Aside from the above recommendation, you can also take a look at the HTML code of the referenced site to get an idea on how they implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to inspect that site with the developer console, you will see that they've got a couple of SVG files that they're animating using CSS transforms for a few seconds on page load:
[image: developer console showing CSS transforms]
The blue highlighted sections are inline CSS that is dynamically being updated by the CSS transforms to reflect the animation (you will see these lines constantly change until their SVG stops animating).

One of their SVGs as an example:
[image: SVG example]

When it comes to animating SVGs for anything as intricate as this or more, I personally prefer a JS library called [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/). They have plenty of animation utilities and an awesome support forum to help you get started with a project like this.

Comment: Thanks so much, this gives me a lead to follow at least.